# JS variable hoisting inside closure

Tags: javascript, closures

JS hoists all variables within scope so why does this code throw an exception:

```
(function() {

  function i() {
      console.log(a.a);
  }
  i();
  var a = { a:1 };
})()
```

While this one works:

```
(function() {
  var a = { a:1 };
  function i() {
      console.log(a.a);
  }
  i();

})()
```

What behavior of interpreter causes this?

Comment: the declaration of `a` is hoisted, the assignment stays where it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `a` is already visible, but its value `{a:1}` is not assigned until the `var` is reached by the execution. Things are somewhat different for local functions declared with `function foo(){...}` because the names are bound to the respective functions/closures before the execution starts.

If you call the closure `i` before assigning `a` a value you get the problem, however with

```
(function(){
     function i(){
         console.log(foo());
     }
     i();
     function foo() { return 42; }
})();
```

the output is 42 and there's no error.

Note that this is true because the `function` statement is used... changing the code to

```
(function(){
     function i(){
         console.log(foo());
     }
     i();
     var foo = function(){ return 42; }
})();
```

gives an error because in this case when `i()` is executed `foo` is not yet bound to the function (like in your case).